# Silverlight Pixel Api

Tags: silverlight, pixel

Lets say I have a black and white .jpeg image.  How could I change the white pixels in the jpeg image to red using the hexidecimal format (ie going from #FFFFFFFF to #FFFF4F4B)?

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a Pixel Shader Bitmap Effect.
[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/synergist/archive/2009/05/15/need-help-with-my-chroma-key-pixel-shader-algorithm.aspx) is a similar example.

Comment: you should be careful with the Bitmap Effects, they can REALLY stomp on performance.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using silverlight 3 then you should look at [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx)
[here is a sample](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/03/23/silverlight-3-s-new-writeablebitmap.aspx)